Is there a way to Disabling chrome's auto-translate feature to force me to work on my English better？
Note that this is not about how to disable automatic translation of my web pages, or disable popup boxes, but how to disable chrome's own translation feature from appearing in my right-click menu for the purpose of enforcing that I have to read the original English text, and doing so in order to prevent me from being lazy and reading my own native language.
Is there such a way?

From this website: https://www.howtogeek.com/407924/how-to-turn-translation-on-or-off-in-chrome/
You must:

Open the settings 

Go to the advanced option 

Unfold on the language option 

And finally, turn off the option 


Note, you must restart chrome after you change any settings in order for then to take effect
